# Why do i get this TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, iterator

My code is below. Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error:
"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" regarding my "for i, crp" line?

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy

from gensim import corpora, models
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(sws_removed)

corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in sws_removed]

document_topic = defaultdict(list)
for i, crp in enumerate(corpus):
    probs = ldamodel.get_document_topics(crp)
    max_topic = probs.argsort()[-1]
    document_topic[max_topic].append(i)
```

Comment: What is corpus? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem.

Comment: `corpus` is almost certainly of type `int`, which is what it's saying can't be iterated over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the error is in the for statement, but in the line

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in sws_removed]
```

Sws_removed must be a list of unicode characters. If it is not a list, but an int, it might give you that error. In fact, this code gives that error 

    `from collections import defaultdict
    import gensim
    from gensim import corpora
    lofs = 13
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(lofs)
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in lofs]
    ldamodel = gensim.models.LdaModel(corpus=corpus)
    document_topic = defaultdict(list)
    for i, crp in enumerate(corpus):
        probs = ldamodel.get_document_topics(crp)`

And this is the stacktrace (which is always useful to post)

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/python/stackoverflow/numpcorpora/numcorpora.py", line 9, in 
>       dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(lofs)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\dictionary.py", line 58, in **init**
>       self.add_documents(documents, prune_at=prune_at)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\dictionary.py", line 111, in add_documents
>       for docno, document in enumerate(documents):
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Now replace `lofs = 13` with `lofs = ['list of words'.split()]` and it will run fine, giving the following output:

```
[[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]]
[(50, 0.75250000000000183)]
```

So check your sws_removed. It is an int, and not a list of unicode characters, as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

is `type(corpus)` an int?

it needs to be an iterable:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate